# Perl - Missing Comma on output

Tags: perl

I have an update in my script to format a file and remove an extra comma based off the DOE J field, some of my lines have an extra and some don't. I got it to work but the problem I am now having is that I am missing one of my commas and I am not sure why it is happening.

```
  while(<IN>) {
        my $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/^(([^,]+,){13})([^,]*),*([^,]*)(,[^,]+,.*)$/\1\3\4\5/;
        print OUT "$line";
  }
```

INPUT:

```
555555,Service Location,06/30,210,OD44000,07/01/2011,09/01/2000,09/04/2000,1,07/01/2000,04/18/2000,2000-06-23 00:00:00,2000-07-01 00:00:00,DOE, J,11950000,349000,200000000A,07/13/2000,2000-07-27 00:00:00,20010002000600CAA,8,1, ,6,Yes,,No,,No,01001,2800038000,**SUM**,0,400,38648.44,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0
555555,Service Location,06/30,210,OD44000,07/01/2011,09/01/2000,09/04/2000,1,07/01/2000,04/18/2000,2000-06-23 00:00:00,2000-07-01 00:00:00,DOE J,11950000,349000,200000000A,07/13/2000,2000-07-27 00:00:00,20010002000600CAA,8,1, ,6,Yes,,No,,No,01001,2800038000,**SUM**,0,400,38648.44,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0
```

OUTPUT:

```
555555,Service Location,06/30,210,OD44000,07/01/2011,09/01/2000,09/04/2000,1,07/01/2000,04/18/2000,2000-06-23 00:00:00,2000-07-01 00:00:00,DOE J,11950000,349000,200000000A,07/13/2000,2000-07-27 00:00:00,20010002000600CAA,8,1, ,6,Yes,,No,,No,01001,2800038000,**SUM**,0,400,38648.44,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0
555555,Service Location,06/30,210,OD44000,07/01/2011,09/01/2000,09/04/2000,1,07/01/2000,04/18/2000,2000-06-23 00:00:00,2000-07-01 00:00:00,DOE J11950000,349000,200000000A,07/13/2000,2000-07-27 00:00:00,20010002000600CAA,8,1, ,6,Yes,,No,,No,01001,2800038000,**SUM**,0,400,38648.44,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0
```

Expected Output:

```
555555,Service Location,06/30,210,OD44000,07/01/2011,09/01/2000,09/04/2000,1,07/01/2000,04/18/2000,2000-06-23 00:00:00,2000-07-01 00:00:00,DOE J,11950000,349000,200000000A,07/13/2000,2000-07-27 00:00:00,20010002000600CAA,8,1, ,6,Yes,,No,,No,01001,2800038000,**SUM**,0,400,38648.44,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0
555555,Service Location,06/30,210,OD44000,07/01/2011,09/01/2000,09/04/2000,1,07/01/2000,04/18/2000,2000-06-23 00:00:00,2000-07-01 00:00:00,DOE J,11950000,349000,200000000A,07/13/2000,2000-07-27 00:00:00,20010002000600CAA,8,1, ,6,Yes,,No,,No,01001,2800038000,**SUM**,0,400,38648.44,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,,,6018.32,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0
```

Comment: All those `*`, one after another, are quite nasty to mentally track; they allow for some rather unexpected patterns to be matched.  Can you explain in words how one is supposed to make distinction between `DOE, J, ...` and `DOE J, ...` ?  (They both involve strings followed by commas.)  I can't figure out from your code how it's supposed to tell them apart.  (The `DOE,J` need be corrected, right?)

Comment: ( Is it always strings `DOE` and `J`? I assume there could be other words instead.  Is it always about the fields 13-and-perhaps-14, as text with numbers in the fields right before and after them? Is the total number of fields in the whole line fixed? etc... )

Comment: The problem here seems to be your input data. It's trying to be comma-separated, but then it puts a random comma inside a field. Can you get that fixed so that any text fields which might include commas are quoted? That way, you can then use something like Text::CSV_XS to parse the data.

Comment: Each piece the brackets are the place holder for what is being done, therefore, the part where there is no bracket is the value I am looking for and want to eliminate, which is the extra comma in the name. There after it will locate the non-comma fields and comma fields thereafter. The solution I found was to state how many more commas there are thereafter and copy the non-comma fields and comma fields.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reaching out to an old co-worker and this is what he suggested, and it worked. In my file, I have a comma count of 90 after the name, therefore I stated, this pattern, is 90 times thereafter.

```
  while(<IN>) {
        my $line = $_;
             $line =~ s/^(([^,]*,){13})([^,]*),*([^,]*)((,[^,]*){90})/\1\3\4\5/;
        print OUT "$line";
  }
```